# VSTS: Coded Web Tests, organize or reorder test results

Tags: visual-studio, webtest

I have been asked to include a comment to the Test Results in Visual Studio(Testing Suite) after the URLS.

Unfortunately, I cannot  get any comments to post after the URL. I have tried adding the comment in all of the events available; PostRequest, Validation, etc and all of them are executed before the final addition of the URL to the results. Like Below.  Essentially I need the COMMENT to be below the url. Any advice?

Example Test results:

JUST A COMMENT!

www.whataver.com/api/test

JUST A COMMENT!

www.whataver.com/api/test

```
public class Test01 : CustomTestBase
{
    public Test01()
    {
        var get = QueueGet("/api/test", HttpStatusCode.OK);

        get.PostRequest += (object sender, PostRequestEventArgs args) =>
        {
            if (args.ResponseExists)
            {
                 AddCommentToResult(" JUST A COMMENT! ");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No response");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to implement a virtual function in our base class, and override in all the derived classes. Having the most derived one include the strings I wanted in the comment

Comment: public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()

        {
                yield return req;

    // after all the work

                SpecialComment();

        }

Comment: public virtual void SpecialComment()
        {
            //AddCommentToResult("virtual special, should only be overridden");
        }

Comment: TLDR; Any comments you want execute after all the exposed events need to be after the yield return request; line